# Resistor to change 12 volts to 4.5 volts with 20mA current

Tags: resistors

I'm a newbie working with LEDs and I need to use a resistor to change 12 volts to 4.5 volts, with 20mA current, though can't figure out the correct resistor.
Just to give you more detail, it's for a string of (i think) 20 LED's, they run fine on battery pack of 4.5 volts (this is how they were bought), though I need to add a 12v infra-red sensor and a 12v battery pack to run the whole thing.
So I need a resistor to make the 20mA string of 20 LEDs to run and not burn out.
There is some maths (and electronics lingo^^ :) that I can't figure out to find the correct resistor, I was hoping it's an easy question others may know how to answer.
The string of LEDs are already installed and glued deep within an art project so I only have 1 chance to get it right else the entire $3000 project is bust... ! any help greatly appreciated.
thanks so much!
Lucy

Comment: XY problem alert. Why use a resistor, can't you afford a voltage regulator?

Comment: You need to look up Ohms law to work out the resistance. The answer you want is 375 Ohms. The nearest value commonly available is 390 Ohms. A 1/4 Watt resistor will do but ideally buy a 1/2 Watt.

Comment: @SteveG 100% sure? He wrote "20mA" and later "20 LEDs". I won't bet that there aren't 10 parallel groups of 2 green LEDs + one R per group which each 20mA. Without knowing the forward voltage (or color) of the LEDs and/or how the 20 LEDs are connected and if the 20mA is in sum or per LED I wouldn't make such a suggestion if the project is worth 3000$

Comment: Did you **measure** the current at 4.5V or is this just a guess because you read somewhere LEDs take 20mA?  I seriously doubt your value of 20mA to drive a string of 20 LEDs at 4.5V, its more likely to be 200mA . This makes a big difference to any solution. Try the 390 ohm resistor from a 12V source as suggested by Steve (it won't burn out the LEDs) but I'm willing to bet the LEDs won't be very bright or they'll fail to light up at all **OR** you can measure the current taken from a 4.5V battery and let us know.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a regulator. In this case, a car usb charger + one 1n4001 or similar diode would work just fine. The car usb charger is a 12V to 5V regulator. The diode will bring it down 0.7V to about 4.3V.

Comment: and if the project is $3000 worth, he perhaps should ask someone with electrical skills to help him do the wiring...

Comment: https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/219

Answer (score 0):

I did it elthe following way. I had to install a flashlight LED to the car. And I did connected a USB port to 12 v and then I did use the USB port to feed the 4.5 volt lamp.